# Django ImageField in Model and Forms

Tags: python-3.x, django-2.1

I have a model which takes only image name as text. Assume I cannot modify the models class. I have added ImageField in the forms class. It appears in the HTML form. However, I can't save the Image file in the media folder.Model fields get saved and stored in the database.

settings.py

```
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media')
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
```

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to know what is happening without seeing your files. Have you looked at the [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/forms/api/#binding-uploaded-files) for binding a file/image field to the form? If you do that then you should be able to manipulate it and save it however you want to from your view.